# Extractor fan or dehumidifier?

Tags: ventilation, humidity

My home has a consistent high relative humidity (70-90%, depending on whether I am hanging clothes to dry as I don't have a dryer) during winter. Thankfully, it seems that enough ventilation is available such that mold does not appear, however, I am concerned it could or that the high humidity can be bad for me and my family.

There are 3 vents in the flat: one in the kitchen and two in cupboards. Should I buy extractor fans for all of the vents or at least the kitchen, or should I get a dehumidifier?

The flat is 3 bedrooms, one living room, one bathroom and a kitchen.

Thanks in advance,

Pablo

Comment: What is the climate like outside in Winter, where you are?  How is the house heated? In my climate (0°C to -30°C typical winter temperatures), things tend to be quite dry inside heated buildings in winter.

Comment: I think a whole-house dehumidifier is the better choice, as the extractor works better when extracting the heat by pulling in fresh air to generate air flow, which is not desirable in the winter.

Comment: The flat is heated with gas central heating. the climate during winter is wet and ranges from -3 to 10 C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a dehumidifier unless you don't pay for heat.

You don't want humidity over 60% as dust mites, mold, fungus, virus and bacteria all multiply quicker.

A dehumidifier will take water out of the air and the waste product is heat.  If you dump the water down the drain before it heats to room temp you gain additional heat.

Answer (score 0):

Check into your local laws, venting a dryer into a living area is illegal in many areas. I am not giving advice just a suggestion. If it is your home and the dryer is close to an outside wall it is very easy to install a vent with a damper to prevent outside air from ingressing into your laundry area. If it is not your home talk to the landlord. If it is a gas dryer it can kill you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My original question was not clear. I have ammened it to say that I do not have a clothes dryer.

Comment: You should have an exhaust fan in the bathroom, just hang the clothing there to dry. If the bottom of the door is not a tight seal just close the door. You could use one of the small fans you use in the summer and place it in the bathroom to keep air moving.

Answer (score 0):

Depends where the house is located/ how much it is heated. In IL, enough winter heat will be put in so that humidity will not be high. On the Gulf coast, with less heating and no dryer, an exhaust fan could be helpful. In the Houston area, with a gas dryer , we have no humidity build-up.